# MVC3 layout using jquery and partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

What I am trying to achieve is a layout view kind of functionality, where I have tabs at the top of pop up window which is also a partial view and I can click on them to navigate between different pages with the help of jquery and partial views. Pretty much a layout kind of functionality.[image]

Please let me know if there is a video tutorial for it or any guidance on how to achieve this.
Also I will need to pass the id to the partial view to fetch the information.

Thanks!

Comment: did you search for "jQuery tab" in google ? There are a lot..

Comment: I will look for it. Thanks! Is there anything specific that will deal with my situation?

Comment: jQuery UI dialog, jQuery tabs then the patiences to try the code yourself

Comment: I am on a tight deadline. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you call *"ASP.NET MVC"* framework just *"MVC"*, it is like referring to IE as *"the internet"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it:

1) Like some people mentioned in comments above you can implement JQuery [.tab()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). Here is a tutorial you can follow:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs

2) You can create a partial view that will be displayed as a JQuery .dialog(). Within that partial view, at the top you can have three links corresponding to three tabs titles.

Each link will call JQuery .show() on a div that will contains a "tab" content you want to display and .hide() for others. I usually just pass in the id of a div (tab ) I want to display to something like this:

```
function displaySelectedTab(selectedTab) {
    $("#tab1").hide();
    $("#tab2").hide();
    $("#tab3").hide();

    $(selectedTab).show();
}
```

3) Third option is to have separate Partial Views for each tab. You can use JQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method do load different tabs into a Div section:

```
var url = "/ControllerName/ActionViewThatReturnsPartialView/
$("#popup-div-placeholder").html("").load(url);
```

To implement a popup window mechanism you can take advantage of JQuery [.dialog()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Hope it helps.